# Jssor - Slider not loading images

Tags: javascript, html, slider, jssor

The slider works perfectly in development, but as soon as I upload the html file it stops working. The container still appears on the webpage but it acts as if it can't find the images (like a broken link).

reference: http://allinthedetail.tomangopawpadilla.co.za/

I used Zazanaire to create the slider and copied the code from there. Please see below for the code:

```
<!-- Slider -->
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
                        <Script>
                            /* Slider code */
                            (function(g,f,b,d,c,e,A){/*! Jssor */
                            $Jssor$=g.$Jssor$=g.$Jssor$||{};new(function(){});var m=function(){var b=this,a={};b.gb=b.addEventListener=function(b,c){if(typeof c!="function")return;if(!a[b])a[b]=[];a[b].push(c)};b.removeEventListener=function(e,d){var b=a[e];if(typeof d!="function")return;else if(!b)return;for(var c=0;c<b.length;c++)if(d==b[c]){b.splice(c,1);return}};b.g=function(e){var c=a[e],d=[];if(!c)return;for(var b=1;b<arguments.length;b++)d.push(arguments[b]);for(var b=0;b<c.length;b++)try{c[b].apply(g,d)}catch(f){}}},h;(function(){h=function(a,b){this.x=typeof a=="number"?a:0;this.y=typeof b=="number"?b:0};})();var k={le:function(a){return a},ec:function(a){return-b.cos(a*b.PI)/2+.5},ne:function(a){return-a*(a-2)},tb:function(a){return a*a*a}},i={ke:function(a){return(~a&3)+(a&12)},Wd:function(a){return(~a&12)+(a&3)},gd:function(a){return(a&3)==1},hd:function(a){return(a&3)==2},Zc:function(a){return(a&12)==4},Pc:function(a){return(a&12)==8},cd:function(a){return(a&3)>0},Lc:function(a){return(a&12)>0}},s={Vd:37,Sd:39},o,n={ee:0,de:1,Ae:2,cf:3,bf:4,ef:5},z=1,v=2,x=3,w=4,y=5,j,a=new function(){var i=this,m=n.ee,j=0,q=0,P=0,s=0,cb=navigator.appName,k=navigator.userAgent;function D(){if(!m)if(cb=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"&&!!g.attachEvent&&!!g.ActiveXObject){var d=k.indexOf("MSIE");m=n.de;q=parseFloat(k.substring(d+5,k.indexOf(";",d)));/*@cc_on P=@_jscript_version@*/;j=f.documentMode||q}else if(cb=="Netscape"&&!!g.addEventListener){var c=k.indexOf("Firefox"),a=k.indexOf("Safari"),h=k.indexOf("Chrome"),b=k.indexOf("AppleWebKit");if(c>=0){m=n.Ae;j=parseFloat(k.substring(c+8))}else if(a>=0){var i=k.substring(0,a).lastIndexOf("/");m=h>=0?n.bf:n.cf;j=parseFloat(k.substring(i+1,a))}if(b>=0)s=parseFloat(k.substring(b+12))}else{var e=/(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/i.exec(k);if(e){m=n.ef;j=parseFloat(e[2])}}}function l(){D();return m==z}function G(){return l()&&(j<6||f.compatMode=="BackCompat")}function V(){D();return m==v}function M(){D();return m==x}function hb(){D();return m==w}function ib(){D();return m==y}function R(){return M()&&s>534&&s<535}function r(){return l()&&j<9}var B;function u(a){if(!B){p(["transform","WebkitTransform","msTransform","MozTransform","OTransform"],function(b){if(!i.Tb(a.style[b])){B=b;return c}});B=B||"transform"}return B}function ab(a){return Object.prototype.toString.call(a)}var J;function p(a,c){if(ab(a)=="[object Array]"){for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)if(c(a[b],b,a))break}else for(var d in a)if(c(a[d],d,a))break}function jb(){if(!J){J={};p(["Boolean","Number","String","Function","Array","Date","RegExp","Object"],function(a){J["[object "+a+"]"]=a.toLowerCase()})}return J}function t(a){return a==d?String(a):jb()[ab(a)]||"object"}function bb(b,a){setTimeout(b,a||0)}function I(b,d,c){var a=!b||b=="inherit"?"":b;p(d,function(c){var b=c.exec(a);if(b){var d=a.substr(0,b.index),e=a.substr(b.lastIndex+1,a.length-(b.lastIndex+1));a=d+e}});a=c+(a.indexOf(" ")!=0?" ":"")+a;return a}function W(b,a){if(j<9)b.style.filter=a}function fb(b,a,c){if(P<9){var e=b.style.filter,g=new RegExp(/[\s]*progid:DXImageTransform\.Microsoft\.Matrix\([^\)]*\)/g),f=a?"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+a[0][0]+", M12="+a[0][1]+", M21="+a[1][0]+", M22="+a[1][1]+", SizingMethod='auto expand')":"",d=I(e,[g],f);W(b,d);i.af(b,c.y);i.Xe(b,c.x)}}i.Zb=l;i.Ze=V;i.Ye=M;i.rb=hb;i.Db=ib;i.C=r;i.hf=function(){return j};i.Ge=function(){return q||j};i.Bb=function(){return s};i.t=bb;i.Wb=function(a){if(i.wc(a))a=f.getElementById(a);return a};i.Xb=function(a){return a?a:g.event};i.xc=function(a){a=i.Xb(a);var b=new h;if(a.type=="DOMMouseScroll"&&V()&&j<3){b.x=a.screenX;b.y=a.screenY}else if(typeof a.pageX=="number"){b.x=a.pageX;b.y=a.pageY}else if(typeof a.clientX=="number"){b.x=a.clientX+f.body.scrollleft+f.documentElement.scrollleft;b.y=a.clientY+f.body.scrolltop+f.documentElement.scrolltop}return b};i.tc=function(b){if(l()&&q<9){var a=/opacity=([^)]*)/.exec(b.style.filter||"");return a?parseFloat(a[1])/100:1}else return parseFloat(b.style.opacity||"1")};i.Gb=function(c,a,f){if(l()&&q<9){var h=c.style.filter||"",i=new RegExp(/[\s]*alpha\([^\)]*\)/g),e=b.round(100*a),d="";if(e<100||f)d="alpha(opacity="+e+") ";var g=I(h,[i],d);W(c,g)}else c.style.opacity=a==1?"":b.round(a*100)/100};function O(g,c){var f=c.l||0,e=c.Gc||1;if(r()){var k=i.Se(f/180*b.PI,e,e);fb(g,!f&&e==1?d:k,i.Ue(k,c.fb,c.eb))}else{var h=u(g);if(h){var j="rotate("+f%360+"deg) scale("+e+")";if(a.rb()&&s>535)j+="perspective(2000px)";g.style[h]=j}}}i.Me=function(b,a){if(R())bb(i.J(d,O,b,a));else O(b,a)};i.Le=function(b,c){var a=u(b);if(a)b.style[a+"Origin"]=c};i.Oe=function(a,c){if(l()&&q<9||q<10&&G())a.style.zoom=c==1?"":c;else{var b=u(a);if(b){var f="scale("+c+")",e=a.style[b],g=new RegExp(/[\s]*scale\(.*?\)/g),d=I(e,[g],f);a.style[b]=d}}};i.Je=function(a){a.style[u(a)]="perspective(2000px)"};i.kf=function(a){a.style[u(a)]="none"};i.o=function(a,c,d,b){a=i.Wb(a);if(a.addEventListener){c=="mousewheel"&&a.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",d,b);a.addEventListener(c,d,b)}else if(a.attachEvent){a.attachEvent("on"+c,d);b&&a.setCapture&&a.setCapture()}};i.jf=function(a,c,d,b){a=i.Wb(a);if(a.removeEventListener){c=="mousewheel"&&a.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",d,b);a.removeEventListener(c,d,b)}else if(a.detachEvent){a.detachEvent("on"+c,d);b&&a.releaseCapture&&a.releaseCapture()}};i.jb=function(a){a=i.Xb(a);a.preventDefault&&a.preventDefault();a.cancel=c;a.returnValue=e};i.J=function(e,d){for(var b=[],a=2;a<arguments.length;a++)b.push(arguments[a]);var c=function(){for(var c=b.concat([]),a=0;a<arguments.length;a++)c.push(arguments[a]);return d.apply(e,c)};return c};i.Ne=function(a){a.innerHTML=""};i.S=function(c){for(var b=[],a=c.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)a.nodeType==1&&b.push(a);return b};function N(a,c,b,f){if(!b)b="u";for(a=a?a.firstChild:d;a;a=a.nextSibling)if(a.nodeType==1){if(a.getAttribute(b)==c)return a;if(f){var e=N(a,c,b,f);if(e)return e}}}i.lb=N;function S(a,c,e){for(a=a?a.firstChild:d;a;a=a.nextSibling)if(a.nodeType==1){if(a.tagName==c)return a;if(e){var b=S(a,c,e);if(b)return b}}}i.Ve=S;function T(a,e,g){var b=[];for(a=a?a.firstChild:d;a;a=a.nextSibling)if(a.nodeType==1){(!e||a.tagName==e)&&b.push(a);if(g){var f=T(a,e,c);if(f.length)b=b.concat(f)}}return b}i.ff=T;i.i=function(c){for(var b=1;b<arguments.length;b++){var a=arguments[b];if(a)for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d]}return c};i.Tb=function(a){return t(a)=="undefined"};i.Kc=function(a){return t(a)=="function"};i.wb=Array.isArray||function(a){return t(a)=="array"};i.wc=function(a){return t(a)=="string"};i.Yb=function(a){return!isNaN(parseFloat(a))&&isFinite(a)};i.c=p;i.Cc=function(a){return i.ld("DIV",a)};i.ld=function(b,a){a=a||f;return a.createElement(b)};i.hb=function(){};i.T=function(a,b){return a.getAttribute(b)};i.Id=function(b,c,a){b.setAttribute(c,a)};i.Pd=function(a){return a.style.display};i.Eb=function(b,a){b.style.display=a||""};i.Hb=function(b,a){b.style.overflow=a};i.vc=function(a){return a.parentNode};i.y=function(a){i.Eb(a,"none")};i.u=function(a,b){i.Eb(a,b==e?"none":"")};i.Dd=function(a){return a.style.position};i.x=function(b,a){b.style.position=a};i.id=function(a){return parseInt(a.style.top,10)};i.Y=function(a,c){a.style.top=b.round(c*100)/100+"px"};i.Xc=function(a){return parseInt(a.style.left,10)};i.Z=function(a,c){a.style.left=b.round(c*100)/100+"px"};i.G=function(a){return parseInt(a.style.width,10)};i.yb=function(c,a){c.style.width=b.max(a,0)+"px"};i.P=function(a){return parseInt(a.style.height,10)};i.vb=function(c,a){c.style.height=b.max(a,0)+"px"};i.vd=function(a){return a.style.cssText};i.Tc=function(b,a){b.style.cssText=a};i.Vc=function(b,a){b.removeAttribute(a)};i.Xe=function(b,a){b.style.marginleft=a+"px"};i.af=function(b,a){b.style.margintop=a+"px"};i.qc=function(a){return parseInt(a.style.zIndex)||0};i.ab=function(c,a){c.style.zIndex=b.ceil(a)};i.ed=function(b,a){b.style.backgroundcolor=a};i.pd=function(){return l()&&j<10};i.ud=function(d,c){if(c)d.style.clip="rect("+b.round(c.b)+"px "+b.round(c.h)+"px "+b.round(c.f)+"px "+b.round(c.d)+"px)";else{var g=i.vd(d),f=[new RegExp(/[\s]*clip: rect\(.*?\)[;]?/i),new RegExp(/[\s]*cliptop: .*?[;]?/i),new RegExp(/[\s]*clipright: .*?[;]?/i),new RegExp(/[\s]*clipbottom: .*?[;]?/i),new RegExp(/[\s]*clipleft: .*?[;]?/i)],e=I(g,f,"");a.Tc(d,e)}};i.D=function(){return+new Date};i.B=function(b,a){b.appendChild(a)};i.xd=function(b,a){p(a,function(a){i.B(b,a)})};i.jc=function(c,b,a){c.insertBefore(b,a)};i.bd=function(b,a){b.removeChild(a)};i.Bd=function(b,a){p(a,function(a){i.bd(b,a)})};i.Ad=function(a){i.Bd(a,i.S(a))};i.Ed=function(b,a){return parseInt(b,a||10)};i.uc=function(a){return parseFloat(a)};i.zc=function(b,a){var c=f.body;while(a&&b!=a&&c!=a)try{a=a.parentNode}catch(d){return e}return b==a};i.r=function(b,a){return b.cloneNode(a)};function L(b,a,c){a.onload=d;a.abort=d;b&&b(a,c)}i.X=function(e,b){if(i.Db()&&j<11.6||!e)L(b,d);else{var a=new Image;a.onload=i.J(d,L,b,a);a.onabort=i.J(d,L,b,a,c);a.src=e}};i.wd=function(e,b,f){var d=e.length+1;function c(a){d--;if(b&&a&&a.src==b.src)b=a;!d&&f&&f(b)}a.c(e,function(b){a.X(b.src,c)});c()};var Z={k:i.tc,b:i.id,d:i.Xc,m:i.G,p:i.P,I:i.Dd,A:i.qc},F={k:i.Gb,b:i.Y,d:i.Z,m:i.yb,p:i.vb,a:i.ud,Cb:i.Me,I:i.x,A:i.ab};function H(){return F}function U(){H();F.Cb=F.Cb;return F}i.Md=H;i.Nd=U;i.Hd=function(c,b){H();var a={};p(b,function(d,b){if(Z[b])a[b]=Z[b](c)});return a};i.z=function(c,b){var a=H();p(b,function(d,b){a[b]&&a[b](c,d)})};i.Fd=function(b,a){U();i.z(b,a)};o=new function(){var a=this;function b(d,g){for(var j=d[0].length,i=d.length,h=g[0].length,f=[],c=0;c<i;c++)for(var k=f[c]=[],b=0;b<h;b++){for(var e=0,a=0;a<j;a++)e+=d[c][a]*g[a][b];k[b]=e}return f}a.Lb=function(d,c){var a=b(d,[[c.x],[c.y]]);return new h(a[0][0],a[1][0])}};i.Se=function(d,a,c){var e=b.cos(d),f=b.sin(d);return[[e*a,-f*c],[f*a,e*c]]};i.Ue=function(d,c,a){var e=o.Lb(d,new h(-c/2,-a/2)),f=o.Lb(d,new h(c/2,-a/2)),g=o.Lb(d,new h(c/2,a/2)),i=o.Lb(d,new h(-c/2,a/2));return new h(b.min(e.x,f.x,g.x,i.x)+c/2,b.min(e.y,f.y,g.y,i.y)+a/2)}};j=function(m,r,g,O,C,y){m=m||0;var f=this,q,n,o,x,z=0,B,M,L,D,j=0,t=0,E,l=m,i,h,p,u=[],A;function I(b){i+=b;h+=b;l+=b;j+=b;t+=b;a.c(u,function(a){a,a.Ab(b)})}function N(a,b){var c=a-i+m*b;I(c);return h}function w(w,G){var m=w;if(p&&(m>=h||m<=i))m=((m-i)%p+p)%p+i;if(!E||x||G||j!=m){var o=b.min(m,h);o=b.max(o,i);if(!E||x||G||o!=t){if(y){var s=(o-l)/r;if(g.Jd&&a.rb())s=b.round(s*r/16)/r*16;if(g.fc)s=1-s;var e={};for(var n in y){var R=M[n]||1,J=L[n]||[0,1],k=(s-J[0])/J[1];k=b.min(b.max(k,0),1);k=k*R;var H=b.floor(k);if(k!=H)k-=H;var Q=B[n]||B.s,I=Q(k),q,K=C[n],F=y[n];if(a.Yb(F))q=K+(F-K)*I;else{q=a.i({v:{}},C[n]);a.c(F.v,function(c,b){var a=c*I;q.v[b]=a;q[b]+=a})}e[n]=q}if(C.e)e.Cb={l:e.l||0,Gc:e.e,fb:g.fb,eb:g.eb};if(y.a&&g.N){var v=e.a.v,D=(v.b||0)+(v.f||0),z=(v.d||0)+(v.h||0);e.d=(e.d||0)+z;e.b=(e.b||0)+D;e.a.d-=z;e.a.h-=z;e.a.b-=D;e.a.f-=D}if(e.a&&a.pd()&&!e.a.b&&!e.a.d&&e.a.h==g.fb&&e.a.f==g.eb)e.a=d;a.c(e,function(b,a){A[a]&&A[a](O,b)})}f.oc(t-l,o-l)}t=o;a.c(u,function(b,c){var a=w<j?u[u.length-c-1]:b;a.E(w,G)});var P=j,N=w;j=m;E=c;f.zb(P,N)}}function F(a,c){c&&a.ub(h,1);h=b.max(h,a.Q());u.push(a)}function H(){if(q){var d=a.D(),e=b.min(d-z,30),c=j+e*o;z=d;if(c*o>=n*o)c=n;w(c);if(!x&&c*o>=n*o)J(D);else a.t(H,g.H)}}function v(d,e,g){if(!q){q=c;x=g;D=e;d=b.max(d,i);d=b.min(d,h);n=d;o=n<j?-1:1;f.Dc();z=a.D();H()}}function J(a){if(q){x=q=D=e;f.Ec();a&&a()}}f.Ac=function(a,b,c){v(a?j+a:h,b,c)};f.Bc=function(b,a,c){v(b,a,c)};f.O=function(){J()};f.od=function(a){v(a)};f.M=function(){return j};f.rc=function(){return n};f.qb=function(){return t};f.E=w;f.pc=function(){w(i,c)};f.N=function(a){w(j+a)};f.rd=function(){return q};f.Kd=function(a){p=a};f.ub=N;f.Ab=I;f.L=function(a){F(a,0)};f.cc=function(a){F(a,1)};f.Q=function(){return h};f.zb=a.hb;f.Dc=a.hb;f.Ec=a.hb;f.oc=a.hb;f.ic=a.D();g=a.i({H:15},g);p=g.yc;A=a.i({},a.Md(),g.ad);i=l=m;h=m+r;var M=g.V||{},L=g.Kb||{};B=a.i({s:a.Kc(g.j)&&g.j||k.ec},g.j)};var q,l={},r;new function(){;function x(b,a,c){c.push(a);b[a]=b[a]||[];b[a].push(c)}l.td=function(d){for(var e=[],a,c=0;c<d.bb;c++)for(a=0;a<d.W;a++)x(e,b.ceil(1e5*b.random())%13,[c,a]);return e};function Q(a){var b=a.qd(a);return a.fc?b.reverse():b}function K(g,f){var d={H:f,q:1,t:0,W:1,bb:1,k:0,e:0,a:0,N:e,Mb:e,F:0,fc:e,qd:l.td,Yc:{zd:0,yd:0},j:k.ec,V:{},sb:[],Kb:{}};a.i(d,g);if(a.Kc(d.j))d.j={s:d.j};d.Qc=b.ceil(d.q/d.H);d.fd=R(d);d.Cd=function(b,a){b/=d.W;a/=d.bb;var f=b+"x"+a;if(!d.sb[f]){d.sb[f]={m:b,p:a};for(var c=0;c<d.W;c++)for(var e=0;e<d.bb;e++)d.sb[f][e+","+c]={b:e*a,h:c*b+b,f:e*a+a,d:c*b}}return d.sb[f]};if(d.Pb){d.Pb=K(d.Pb,f);d.Mb=c}return d}function R(d){var c=d.j;if(!c.s)c.s=k.ec;var e=d.Qc,f=c.mb;if(!f){var g=a.i({},d.j,d.V);f=c.mb={};a.c(g,function(n,l){var g=c[l]||c.s,j=d.V[l]||1;if(!a.wb(g.mb))g.mb=[];var h=g.mb[e]=g.mb[e]||[];if(!h[j]){h[j]=[0];for(var k=1;k<=e;k++){var i=k/e*j,m=b.floor(i);if(i!=m)i-=m;h[j][k]=g(i)}}f[l]=h})}return f}function L(D,k,f,y,m,l){var B=this,v,w={},p={},o=[],h,g,t,r=f.Yc.zd||0,s=f.Yc.yd||0,j=f.Cd(m,l),q=Q(f),E=q.length-1,u=f.q+f.t*E,z=y+u,n=f.Mb,A;z+=a.rb()?260:50;B.Fc=z;B.Ib=function(c){c-=y;var d=c<u;if(d||A){A=d;if(!n)c=u-c;var e=b.ceil(c/f.H);a.c(p,function(c,f){var d=b.max(e,c.Ld);d=b.min(d,c.length-1);if(c.Jc!=d){if(!c.Jc&&!n)a.u(o[f]);else d==c.pf&&n&&a.y(o[f]);c.Jc=d;a.Fd(o[f],c[d])}})}};function x(b){a.kf(b);var c=a.S(b);a.c(c,function(a){x(a)})}k=a.r(k,c);x(k);if(a.C()){var F=!k["no-image"],C=a.ff(k,d,c);a.c(C,function(b){(F||b["jssor-slider"])&&a.Gb(b,a.tc(b),c)})}a.c(q,function(d,k){a.c(d,function(N){var S=N[0],R=N[1],z=S+","+R,u=e,x=e,A=e;if(r&&R%2){if(i.cd(r))u=!u;if(i.Lc(r))x=!x;if(r&16)A=!A}if(s&&S%2){if(i.cd(s))u=!u;if(i.Lc(s))x=!x;if(s&16)A=!A}f.b=f.b||f.a&4;f.f=f.f||f.a&8;f.d=f.d||f.a&1;f.h=f.h||f.a&2;var G=x?f.f:f.b,D=x?f.b:f.f,F=u?f.h:f.d,E=u?f.d:f.h;f.a=G||D||F||E;t={};g={b:0,d:0,k:1,m:m,p:l};h=a.i({},g);v=a.i({},j[z]);if(f.k)g.k=2-f.k;if(f.A){g.A=f.A;h.A=0}var Q=f.W*f.bb>1||f.a;if(f.e||f.l){var P=c;if(a.Zb()&&a.Ge()<9)if(f.W*f.bb>1)P=e;else Q=e;if(P){g.e=f.e?f.e-1:1;h.e=1;if(a.C()||a.Db())g.e=b.min(g.e,2);var K=f.l;if(K==c)K=1;g.l=K*360*(A?-1:1);h.l=0}}if(Q){if(f.a){var y=f.Od||1,o=v.v={};if(G&&D){o.b=j.p/2*y;o.f=-o.b}else if(G)o.f=-j.p*y;else if(D)o.b=j.p*y;if(F&&E){o.d=j.m/2*y;o.h=-o.d}else if(F)o.h=-j.m*y;else if(E)o.d=j.m*y}t.a=v;h.a=j[z]}if(f.F){var q=f.F;if(!u)q=i.ke(q);if(!x)q=i.Wd(q);var M=f.Ub||1,O=f.Nb||1;if(i.gd(q))g.d+=m*M;else if(i.hd(q))g.d-=m*M;if(i.Zc(q))g.b+=l*O;else if(i.Pc(q))g.b-=l*O}a.c(g,function(b,c){if(a.Yb(b))if(b!=h[c])t[c]=b-h[c]});w[z]=n?h:g;var L=b.round(k*f.t/f.H);p[z]=new Array(L);p[z].Ld=L;for(var C=f.Qc,J=0;J<=C;J++){var d={};a.c(t,function(g,c){var m=f.fd[c]||f.fd.s,l=m[f.V[c]||1],k=f.Kb[c]||[0,1],e=(J/C-k[0])/k[1]*C;e=b.round(b.min(C,b.max(e,0)));var j=l[e];if(a.Yb(g))d[c]=h[c]+g*j;else{var i=d[c]=a.i({},h[c]);i.v=[];a.c(g.v,function(c,b){var a=c*j;i.v[b]=a;i[b]+=a})}});if(h.e)d.Cb={l:d.l||0,Gc:d.e,fb:m,eb:l};if(d.a&&f.N){var B=d.a.v,I=(B.b||0)+(B.f||0),H=(B.d||0)+(B.h||0);d.d=(d.d||0)+H;d.b=(d.b||0)+I;d.a.d-=H;d.a.h-=H;d.a.b-=I;d.a.f-=I}d.A=d.A||1;p[z].push(d)}})});q.reverse();a.c(q,function(b){a.c(b,function(d){var g=d[0],f=d[1],e=g+","+f,b=k;if(f||g)b=a.r(k,c);a.z(b,w[e]);a.Hb(b,"hidden");a.x(b,"absolute");D.md(b);o[e]=b;a.u(b,n)})})}r=function(h,l,i,n,p){var e=this,o,f,c,s=0,r=n.sd,k,g=16;function q(){var a=this,b=0;j.call(a,0,o);a.zb=function(d,a){if(a-b>g){b=a;c&&c.Ib(a);f&&f.Ib(a)}};a.nb=k}e.He=function(f){var c=0,e=n.Hc,d=e.length;if(r){if(d>f&&(a.rb()||a.Ye()||a.Ze()))d-=d%f;c=s++%d}else c=b.floor(b.random()*d);e[c]&&(e[c].U=c);return e[c]};e.Re=function(w,x,n,p,a){k=a;a=K(a,g);var m=p.Ic,j=n.Ic;m["no-image"]=!p.Qb;j["no-image"]=!n.Qb;var q=m,r=j,v=a,d=a.Pb||K({},g);if(!a.Mb){q=j;r=m}var s=d.Ab||0;f=new L(h,r,d,b.max(s-d.H,0),l,i);c=new L(h,q,v,b.max(d.H-s,0),l,i);f.Ib(0);c.Ib(0);o=b.max(f.Fc,c.Fc);e.U=w};e.ob=function(){h.ob();f=d;c=d};e.Qe=function(){var a=d;if(c)a=new q;return a};if(a.C()||a.Db()||p&&a.Bb<537)g=32;m.call(e);j.call(e,-1e7,1e7)};function n(o,Wb){var l=this;function rc(){var a=this;j.call(a,-1e8,2e8);a.Te=function(){var c=a.qb(),d=b.floor(c),f=u(d),e=c-b.floor(c);return{U:f,Pe:d,I:e}};a.zb=function(d,a){var e=b.floor(a);if(e!=a&&a>d)e++;Lb(e,c);l.g(n.Fe,u(a),u(d),a,d)}}function qc(){var b=this;j.call(b,0,0,{yc:v});a.c(B,function(a){a.Kd(v);b.cc(a);a.Ab(rb/Rb)})}function pc(){var a=this,b=Kb.ib;j.call(a,-1,2,{j:k.le,ad:{I:Qb},yc:v},b,{I:1},{I:-1});a.Rb=b}function ec(o,m){var a=this,f,g,h,k,b;j.call(a,-1e8,2e8);a.Dc=function(){M=c;Q=d;l.g(n.De,u(x.M()),x.M())};a.Ec=function(){M=e;k=e;var a=x.Te();l.g(n.Ce,u(x.M()),x.M());!a.I&&tc(a.Pe,q)};a.zb=function(d,c){var a;if(k)a=b;else{a=g;if(h)a=i.mf(c/h)*(g-f)+f}x.E(a)};a.Jb=function(b,d,c,e){f=b;g=d;h=c;x.E(b);a.E(0);a.Bc(c,e)};a.gf=function(e){k=c;b=e;a.Ac(e,d,c)};a.lf=function(a){b=a};x=new rc;x.L(o);x.L(m)}function fc(){var c=this,b=Pb();a.ab(b,0);c.ib=b;c.md=function(c){a.B(b,c);a.u(b)};c.ob=function(){a.y(b);a.Ne(b)}}function oc(p,o){var f=this,s,w,H,x,g,y=[],Z,r,bb,G,W,D,k,t,h;j.call(f,-F,F+1,{});function C(a){w&&w.Ob();s&&s.Ob();ab(p,a);s=new I.w(p,I,1);w=new I.w(p,I);w.pc();s.pc()}function db(){s.ic<I.ic&&C()}function M(o,q,m){if(!G){G=c;if(g&&m){var d=m.width,b=m.height,k=d,j=b;if(d&&b&&i.db){if(i.db&3){var h=e,p=L/K*b/d;if(i.db&1)h=p>1;else if(i.db&2)h=p<1;k=h?d*K/b:L;j=h?K:b*L/d}a.yb(g,k);a.vb(g,j);a.Y(g,(K-j)/2);a.Z(g,(L-k)/2)}a.x(g,"absolute");l.g(n.Ee,Ub)}}a.y(q);o&&o(f)}function cb(b,c,d,e){if(e==Q&&q==o&&N)if(!sc){var a=u(b);z.Re(a,o,c,f,d);c.Be();U.ub(a,1);U.E(a);A.Jb(b,b,0)}}function eb(b){if(b==Q&&q==o){if(!k){var a=d;if(z)if(z.U==o)a=z.Qe();else z.ob();db();k=new mc(o,a,f.Ke(),f.Ie());k.kd(h)}!k.rd()&&k.Vb()}}function X(e,c){if(e==o){if(e!=c)B[c]&&B[c].We();h&&h.df();var j=Q=a.D();f.X(a.J(d,eb,j))}else{var g=b.abs(o-e);(!W||g<=i.Mc||v-g<=i.Mc)&&f.X()}}function fb(){if(q==o&&k){k.O();h&&h.ce();h&&h.ae();k.Uc()}}function gb(){q==o&&k&&k.O()}function T(b){if(P)a.jb(b);else l.g(n.be,o,b)}function R(){h=t.pInstance;k&&k.kd(h)}f.X=function(e,b){b=b||x;if(y.length&&!G){a.u(b);if(!bb){bb=c;l.g(n.ie);a.c(y,function(b){if(!b.src){b.src=a.T(b,"src2");a.Eb(b,b["display-origin"])}})}a.wd(y,g,a.J(d,M,e,b))}else M(e,b)};f.je=function(){if(z){var b=z.He(v);if(b){var f=Q=a.D(),c=o+1,e=B[u(c)];return e.X(a.J(d,cb,c,e,b,f),x)}}V(q+i.Wc)};f.Sb=function(){X(o,o)};f.We=function(){h&&h.ce();h&&h.ae();f.Nc();k&&k.he();k=d;C()};f.Be=function(){a.y(p)};f.Nc=function(){a.u(p)};f.fe=function(){h&&h.df()};function ab(b,f,d){d=d||0;if(!D){if(b.tagName=="IMG"){y.push(b);if(!b.src){W=c;b["display-origin"]=a.Pd(b);a.y(b)}}a.C()&&a.ab(b,a.qc(b)+1);if(a.Bb()>0)(E&&(a.Bb()<534||!S)||!E&&a.Bb()<535)&&a.Je(b)}var h=a.S(b);a.c(h,function(h){var j=a.T(h,"u");if(j=="player"&&!t){t=h;if(t.pInstance)R();else a.o(t,"dataavailable",R)}if(j=="caption"){if(!a.Zb()&&!f){var i=a.r(h,c);a.jc(b,i,h);a.bd(b,h);h=i;f=c}}else if(!D&&!d&&!g&&a.T(h,"u")=="image"){g=h;if(g){if(g.tagName=="A"){Z=g;a.z(Z,O);r=a.r(g,e);a.o(r,"click",T);a.z(r,O);a.Eb(r,"block");a.Gb(r,0);a.ed(r,"#000");g=a.Ve(g,"IMG")}g.border=0;a.z(g,O)}}ab(h,f,d+1)})}f.oc=function(c,b){var a=F-b;Qb(H,a)};f.Ke=function(){return s};f.Ie=function(){return w};f.U=o;m.call(f);var J=a.lb(p,"thumb");if(J){a.r(J,c);a.y(J)}a.u(p);x=a.r(Y,c);a.ab(x,1e3);a.o(p,"click",T);C(c);D=c;f.Qb=g;f.jd=r;f.Ic=p;f.Rb=H=p;a.B(H,x);l.gb(203,X);l.gb(22,gb);l.gb(24,fb)}function mc(g,r,v,u){var b=this,m=0,x=0,o,h,d,f,k,s,w,t,p=B[g];j.call(b,0,0);function y(){a.Ad(J);Vb&&k&&p.jd&&a.B(J,p.jd);a.u(J,k||!p.Qb)}function A(){if(s){s=e;l.g(n.ge,g,d,m,h,d,f);b.E(h)}b.Vb()}function C(a){t=a;b.O();b.Vb()}b.Vb=function(){var a=b.qb();if(!G&&!M&&!t&&(a!=d||N&&(!Nb||fb))&&q==g){if(!a){if(o&&!k){k=c;b.Uc(c);l.g(n.Td,g,m,x,o,f)}y()}var e,i=n.dd;if(a==f)return p.je();else if(a==d)e=f;else if(a==h)e=d;else if(!a)e=h;else if(a>d){s=c;e=d;i=n.Ud}else e=b.rc();l.g(i,g,a,m,h,d,f);b.Bc(e,A)}};b.he=function(){z&&z.U==g&&z.ob();var a=b.qb();a<f&&l.g(n.dd,g,-a-1,m,h,d,f)};b.Uc=function(b){r&&a.Hb(bb,b&&r.nb.rf?"":"hidden")};b.oc=function(b,a){if(k&&a>=o){k=e;y();p.Nc();z.ob();l.g(n.Qd,g,m,x,o,f)}l.g(n.Rd,g,a,m,h,d,f)};b.kd=function(a){if(a&&!w){w=a;a.gb($JssorPlayer$.nd,C)}};r&&b.cc(r);o=b.Q();b.Q();b.cc(v);h=v.Q();d=h+i.Oc;u.Ab(d);b.L(u);f=b.Q()}function Qb(e,d){var c=w>0?w:i.cb;a.Z(e,b.round(vb*d*(c&1)));a.Y(e,b.round(wb*d*(c>>1&1)))}function lc(a){P=0;!H&&ic()&&kc(a)}function kc(b){kb=M;G=c;ub=e;Q=d;a.o(f,hb,Sb);a.D();Db=A.rc();A.O();if(!kb)w=0;if(E){var h=b.touches[0];pb=h.clientX;qb=h.clientY}else{var g=a.xc(b);pb=g.x;qb=g.y;a.jb(b)}D=0;X=0;ab=0;C=x.M();l.g(n.Yd,u(C),C,b)}function Sb(d){if(G&&(!a.C()||d.button)){var e;if(E){var j=d.touches;if(j&&j.length>0)e=new h(j[0].clientX,j[0].clientY)}else e=a.xc(d);if(e){var f=e.x-pb,g=e.y-qb;if(b.floor(C)!=C)w=i.cb&H;if((f||g)&&!w){if(H==3)if(b.abs(g)>b.abs(f))w=2;else w=1;else w=H;if(E&&w==1&&b.abs(g)-b.abs(f)>3)ub=c}if(w){var l=g,k=wb;if(w==1){l=f;k=vb}if(D-X<-2)ab=1;else if(D-X>2)ab=0;X=D;D=l;mb=C-D/k/(gb||1);if(D&&w&&!ub){a.jb(d);if(!M)A.gf(mb);else A.lf(mb)}else a.C()&&a.jb(d)}}}else zb(d)}function zb(h){gc();if(G){G=e;a.D();a.jf(f,hb,Sb);P=D;P&&a.jb(h);A.O();var c=x.M();l.g(n.Zd,u(c),c,u(C),C,h);var d=b.floor(C);if(b.abs(D)>=i.gc){d=b.floor(c);d+=ab}var g=b.abs(d-c);g=1-b.pow(1-g,5);if(!P&&kb)A.od(Db);else if(c==d){nb.fe();nb.Sb()}else A.Jb(c,d,g*Mb)}}function dc(a){B[q];q=u(a);nb=B[q];Lb(a);return q}function tc(a,b){w=0;dc(a);l.g(n.Xd,u(a),b)}function Lb(b,c){a.c(R,function(a){a.dc(u(b),b,c)})}function ic(){var a=n.Rc||0;n.Rc|=i.n;return H=i.n&~a}function gc(){if(H){n.Rc&=~i.n;H=0}}function Pb(){var b=a.Cc();a.z(b,O);a.x(b,"absolute");return b}function u(a){return(a%v+v)%v}function ac(b,a){V(b,i.xb,a)}function tb(){a.c(R,function(a){a.ac(a.pb.sf>fb)})}function Yb(b){b=a.Xb(b);var c=b.target?b.target:b.srcElement,d=b.relatedTarget?b.relatedTarget:b.toElement;if(!a.zc(o,c)||a.zc(o,d))return;fb=1;tb();B[q].Sb()}function Xb(){fb=0;tb()}function Zb(){O={m:L,p:K,b:0,d:0};a.c(T,function(b){a.z(b,O);a.x(b,"absolute");a.Hb(b,"hidden");a.y(b)});a.z(Y,O)}function db(b,a){V(b,a,c)}function V(h,g,l){if(Jb&&(!G||i.Sc)){M=c;G=e;A.O();if(a.Tb(g))g=Mb;var f=Ab.qb(),d=h;if(l){d=f+h;if(h>0)d=b.ceil(d);else d=b.floor(d)}var k=(d-f)%v;d=f+k;var j=f==d?0:g*b.abs(k);j=b.min(j,g*F*1.5);A.Jb(f,d,j)}}l.Ac=function(){if(!N){N=c;B[q]&&B[q].Sb()}};l.ue=function(){return a.G(r||o)};l.se=function(c){if(!S||!a.Zb()||a.hf()>=8){if(!r){var b=a.r(o,e);a.Vc(b,"id");a.x(b,"relative");a.Y(b,0);a.Z(b,0);r=a.r(o,e);a.Vc(r,"id");a.Tc(r,"");a.x(r,"absolute");a.Y(r,0);a.Z(r,0);a.yb(r,a.G(o));a.vb(r,a.P(o));a.Le(r,"0 0");a.B(r,b);var d=a.S(o);a.B(o,r);a.xd(b,d);a.u(b);a.u(r)}gb=c/a.G(r);a.Oe(r,gb);a.yb(o,c);a.vb(o,gb*a.P(r))}};m.call(this);l.ib=o=a.Wb(o);var i=a.i({db:0,Mc:1,kb:0,hc:e,Sc:c,Wc:1,Oc:3e3,kc:3,xb:500,mf:k.ne,gc:20,nc:0,Fb:1,mc:0,lc:1,cb:1,n:1},Wb),Z=i.te,I=a.i({w:t,qe:1,re:1},i.ye),ob=i.of,jb=i.qf,W=i.nf,cb=i.lc,r,y=a.lb(o,"slides",d,cb),Y=a.lb(o,"loading",d,cb)||a.Cc(f),Gb=a.lb(o,"navigator",d,cb),Cb=a.lb(o,"thumbnavigator",d,cb),cc=a.G(y),bc=a.P(y);if(i.Fb>1||i.mc)i.n&=i.cb;var O,T=a.S(y),q=-1,nb,v=T.length,L=i.ze||cc,K=i.xe||bc,Ob=i.nc,vb=L+Ob,wb=K+Ob,Rb=i.cb==1?vb:wb,F=b.min(i.Fb,v),bb,w,H,ub,E,R=[],Tb,Eb,Ib,Vb,sc,N,Nb=i.kc,Mb=i.xb,lb,S,rb,Jb=F<v,jc=Jb&&i.n,P,fb=1,M,G,Q,pb=0,qb=0,D,X,ab,Ab,x,U,A,Kb=new fc,gb;N=i.hc;l.pb=Wb;Zb();o["jssor-slider"]=c;a.ab(y,a.qc(y));a.x(y,"absolute");bb=a.r(y);a.jc(a.vc(y),bb,y);if(Z){Vb=Z.ve;lb=Z.w;S=F==1&&v>1&&lb}rb=S||F>=v?0:i.mc;var sb=y,B=[],z,J,yb="mousedown",hb="mousemove",Bb="mouseup",eb,C,kb,Db,mb;if(g.navigator.msPointerEnabled){yb="MSPointerDown";hb="MSPointerMove";Bb="MSPointerUp";eb="MSPointerCancel";if(i.n){var xb="none";if(i.n==1)xb="pan-y";else if(i.n==2)xb="pan-x";a.Id(sb.style,"-ms-touch-action",xb)}}else if("ontouchstart"in g||"createTouch"in f){E=c;yb="touchstart";hb="touchmove";Bb="touchend";eb="touchcancel"}U=new pc;if(S)z=new lb(Kb,L,K,Z,E);a.B(bb,U.Rb);a.Hb(y,"hidden");J=Pb();a.ed(J,"#000");a.Gb(J,0);a.jc(sb,J,sb.firstChild);for(var ib=0;ib<T.length;ib++){var nc=T[ib],Ub=new oc(nc,ib);B.push(Ub)}a.y(Y);Ab=new qc;A=new ec(Ab,U);if(jc){a.o(y,yb,lc);a.o(f,Bb,zb);eb&&a.o(f,eb,zb)}Nb&=E?2:1;if(Gb&&ob){Tb=new ob.w(Gb,ob);R.push(Tb)}if(jb){Eb=new jb.w(o,jb,i.lc);R.push(Eb)}if(Cb&&W){W.kb=i.kb;Ib=new W.w(Cb,W);R.push(Ib)}a.c(R,function(a){a.bc(v,B,Y);a.gb(p.we,ac)});a.o(o,"mouseout",Yb);a.o(o,"mouseover",Xb);tb();i.me&&a.o(f,"keydown",function(a){if(a.keyCode==s.Vd)db(-1);else a.keyCode==s.Sd&&db(1)});l.se(l.ue());A.Jb(i.kb,i.kb,0)}n.be=21;n.Yd=22;n.Zd=23;n.De=24;n.Ce=25;n.ie=26;n.Ee=27;n.Fe=202;n.Xd=203;n.Td=206;n.Qd=207;n.Rd=208;n.dd=209;n.Ud=210;n.ge=211;q=n};var p={we:1};function t(){j.call(this,0,0);this.Ob=a.hb}var u=function(p,k,g){var d=this,h,f=k.sc,o={nb:"t",t:"d",q:"du",Ub:"x",Nb:"y",l:"r",e:"z",k:"f",K:"b"},e={s:function(b,a){if(!isNaN(a.R))b=a.R;else b*=a.pe;return b},k:function(b,a){return this.s(b-1,a)}};e.e=e.k;j.call(d,0,0);function m(r,n){var l=[],i,j=[],c=[];function h(c,d){var b={};a.c(o,function(g,h){var e=a.T(c,g+(d||""));if(e){var f={};if(g=="t")f.R=e;else if(e.indexOf("%")+1)f.pe=a.uc(e)/100;else f.R=a.uc(e);b[h]=f}});return b}function p(){return f[b.floor(b.random()*f.length)]}function d(g){var h;if(g=="*")h=p();else if(g){var e=f[a.Ed(g)]||f[g];if(a.wb(e)){if(g!=i){i=g;c[g]=0;j[g]=e[b.floor(b.random()*e.length)]}else c[g]++;e=j[g];if(a.wb(e)){e=e.length&&e[c[g]%e.length];if(a.wb(e))e=e[b.floor(b.random()*e.length)]}}h=e;if(a.wc(h))h=d(h)}return h}var q=a.S(r);a.c(q,function(b){var c=[];c.ib=b;var f=a.T(b,"u")=="caption";a.c(g?[0,3]:[2],function(o,p){if(f){var l,i;if(o!=2||!a.T(b,"t3")){i=h(b,o);if(o==2&&!i.nb){i.t=i.t||{R:0};i=a.i(h(b,0),i)}}if(i&&i.nb){l=d(i.nb.R);if(l){var j=a.i({t:0,Ub:1,Nb:1},l);a.c(i,function(c,a){var b=(e[a]||e.s).apply(e,[j[a],i[a]]);if(!isNaN(b))j[a]=b});if(!p)if(i.K)c.K=i.K.R||0;else if((g?k.qe:k.re)&2)j.K=0}}c.push(j)}if(n%2&&!p)c.oe=m(b,n+1)});l.push(c)});return l}function n(E,d){var h={j:d.j,V:d.V,Kb:d.Kb,fc:g,Jd:c},k=E,y=a.vc(E),o=a.G(k),n=a.P(k),u=a.G(y),t=a.P(y),f={},l={},m=d.Od||1;if(d.k)f.k=2-d.k;h.fb=o;h.eb=n;if(d.e||d.l){f.e=d.e?d.e-1:1;if(a.C()||a.Db())f.e=b.min(f.e,2);l.e=1;var s=d.l||0;if(s==c)s=1;f.l=s*360;l.l=0}else if(d.a){var z={b:0,h:o,f:n,d:0},D=a.i({},z),e=D.v={},C=d.a&4,v=d.a&8,A=d.a&1,x=d.a&2;if(C&&v){e.b=n/2*m;e.f=-e.b}else if(C)e.f=-n*m;else if(v)e.b=n*m;if(A&&x){e.d=o/2*m;e.h=-e.d}else if(A)e.h=-o*m;else if(x)e.d=o*m;h.N=d.N;f.a=D;l.a=z}var p=d.F,q=0,r=0,w=d.Ub,B=d.Nb;if(i.gd(p))q-=u*w;else if(i.hd(p))q+=u*w;if(i.Zc(p))r-=t*B;else if(i.Pc(p))r+=t*B;if(q||r||h.N){f.d=q+a.Xc(k);f.b=r+a.id(k)}var F=d.q;l=a.i(l,a.Hd(k,f));h.ad=a.Nd();return new j(d.t,F,h,k,l,f)}function l(b,c){a.c(c,function(c){var f,i=c.ib,e=c[0],j=c[1];if(e){f=n(i,e);b=f.ub(a.Tb(e.K)?b:e.K,1)}b=l(b,c.oe);if(j){var g=n(i,j,1);g.ub(b,1);d.L(g);h.L(g)}f&&d.L(f)});return b}d.Ob=function(){d.E(d.Q()*(g||0));h.pc()};h=new j(0,0);l(0,m(p,1))};$Z$t3_starter=function(a){$Z$t3_slider=new q(a,{hc:c,Wc:1,Oc:6e3,lc:1,n:3,mc:0,Fb:1,kc:0,db:0,kb:0,me:c,xb:500,gc:20,nc:0,te:{w:r,Hc:[{q:1e3,k:2}],sd:1,ve:0},ye:{w:u,sc:{L:{q:800,F:1,j:k.tb},R:{q:800,F:2,j:k.tb},T:{q:800,F:4,j:k.tb},B:{q:800,F:8,j:k.tb}}}})}})(window,document,Math,null,true,false)
                        </Script>

                        <!-- Slider Begin -->
                        <div id=$Z$t3 class=z_t3 style="height: 300px; width: 600px; position: relative; margin-left: 0%; padding-left: 0">



                            <!-- Slides Container -->
                            <div style="height: 290px; width: 565px; position: absolute" u="slides">
                            <div><img src="img/aitd/img_home_slide_1.png"></div>
                            <div><img src="img/aitd/img_home_slide_2.png"></div>
                            <div><img src="img/aitd/img_home_slide_3.png"></div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Trigger -->
                            <script>
                                $Z$t3_starter("$Z$t3");
                            </script>


                        </div>

                        <!--Slider End-->
```

Would really appreciate help with this as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images path is img/aitd/img_home_slide_1.png

But it should be img/AITD/img_home_slide_1.png

(it's case sensitive)

Ps : You should prevent direct access to your folders, it can lead to security leaks.

It must be because your dev environment is windows (WAMP), which is not as strict as linux for file paths :)

Comment: Thanks, you freakin rock! Been trying to work out the problem for a week (man do I feel like an id10t) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the images can't be found, then make sure the images are in fact in the right folders you wrote for the src attribute in the img tags.  Further, make sure when you "upload" the html file, to also upload the folders containing those images.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

can't access image http://allinthedetail.tomangopawpadilla.co.za/img/aitd/img_home_slide_1.png

also, please remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
```

in your code because it is of no use.

Comment: check console http://allinthedetail.tomangopawpadilla.co.za/services.html